# Masking influence of dynamic paint

Tags: modifiers, dynamic-paint

I've currently got scene where a mesh with a *Waves* Dynamic Paint modifier which is controlled by a particle system with a Dynamic Paint brush.

However, the Dynamic Paint is influencing parts of the object which I'd like to be stationary:

[image]

The effect range of the particles is small enough not to reach the edges, but the ripples travel further than this range. Is there a way to add a mask or paint weights to control what parts of the mesh the Dynamic Paint modifier influences?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

With *Geometry Nodes*, before the *Dynamic Paint* you can store the position as an attribute that is then used after the *Dynamic Paint* to set the position, a Vertex Group as an input attribute can be used to control where the position will be reverted to the original.

[image]

Here, a single Node Tree is used in two *Geometry Nodes* modifiers to do the work. It will just store the position or revert it depending on the *Revert* boolean input.

[image]